# How to run function in console through Python file?

Tags: python, ubuntu, parameters

I have created this function in a Python file:

```
def abc (xyz):
    return xyz
```

I saved the file in `/var/www/` with the file name `a.py`.

Now I want to run this function in an Ubuntu console and pass a parameter to this function. How can I do  this? I have tried this:

```
jaskaran@jaskaran-Vostro-1550:/var/www$ python3 a.py
```

This does not show me any error. How can I call the function and be able to see the output in the console?

Comment: you can also use ``raw_input()`` to catch inputs in string format

Answer (score 2):

The script is running, it just that it only defines the function, it does not execute it. You need to invoke the function from within your Python script. Typically this is done like this:

```
def abc(xyz):
    print(xyz)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    abc(123)
```

You can pass command line arguments to `abc()` like this:

```
import sys

def abc(xyz):
    print(xyz)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    abc(sys.argv[1])
```

Then you can run it from your shell command line:

```
$ python script.py 123546
123456
```

As you can see, the command line argument "123456" was passed to `abc()` from the sys.argv list which represents the arguments passed to the script (sys.argv[0] is the script name).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ python     
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> from a import abc
>>> abc(123)
123
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this:

```
def abc(xyz):
    print(xyz)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    abc(input("Enter something: "))
```

This will print in the console what you enter as input! ;)

i hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

first thing if you want to run the method abc

you need to know many things `main()`  the excution of program starts from main() in python

```
 def abc(xyz):
       return xyz
 if __name__ == "__main__":
      abc("sundar")
```

to pass arguments like below you need to use `sys.argv`

```
$python a.py "sundar"

import sys
def abc(xyz):
    return xyz
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print abc(sys.argv[1])

#output sundar
```

The Python sys module provides access to any command-line arguments via the `sys.argv`. `sys.argv` is the list of command-line arguments and Here `sys.argv[0]` is the program ie. script name.

Comment: I have write done this condition if __name__ ... but still it's not working, May I write down this in file or console ?

Comment: @Harman you need to give print to see results . if you give return it just return .you may feel function is not working.just change the return to print